# Compile-Time Generic Type Mapping without Reflection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics, types, repository-pattern

In C#, is there any way to map one generic type to another generic type during compile time? I'd like to avoid using Reflection for this question. For example, let's say I would like to have TypeA map to TypeB, and have something similar to the following code work:

```
private void List<U> GetItemList<T>() where T : class <== U is the destination type obtained by the compile-time mapping from T to U
{
    Type U = GetMappedType(typeof(T))   <=== this needs to happen during compile-time
    List<U> returnList = Session.QueryOver<U>().List();
    return returnList;
}

private Type GetMappedType(Type sourceType)
{
    if (sourceType == typeof(TypeA))
        return typeof(TypeB);
}
```

I realize that since I'm using a method call to map the type, that it will not do the mapping during compile time, but is there another way that accomplishes what I'm trying to achieve, only during compile time? I know that the code above is not correct, but I hope you can see what I'm trying to go for.

**In short, I'd like to know if there's a way to map one type to another and have the C# compiler know the type mapping so that the destination type can be used as a Generic Type Parameter to any method that takes a Generic Type Parameter. I'd like to avoid using Reflection.**

*As a side-question*, if I do use Reflection for this, will it make the implementation very resource-heavy?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @dmay I am building a Repository Layer for my app as such: [ Domain Layer <==> Repository Layer (w/ NHibernate types) <==> DB ]. I would like a function that takes in a domain type and a Func<T, bool> and outputs a list of domain types that match the function. The issue is that using NHibernate, I cannot query with the incoming domain type, I have to query with the corresponding repository type. I have a function that maps my domain types to NHibernate types. So I have to convert my domain type to NHibernate type first and then query NHibernate using the resulting NH type. (contd...)

Comment: (...contd) So essentially I have to use a dynamic type as a generic type parameter. I think I may have found a solution for this, and that is using the "dynamic" keyword that was introduced in C# 4.0. It allows the compiler to essentially bypass type safety on an object (as far as I can tell), because you can use it anywhere where the type of the object will be dynamically determined. I am still testing it out, though, so I will post the answer here once I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes dynamic would be the answer. I had the same issue recently where I had to switch repositories based on some values configured in the database.

```
var tableNameWithoutSchema = tableName.Substring(tableName.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
var tableType = string.Format("Library.Namespace.{0}, Library.Name", tableNameWithoutSchema);
var instance = UnitofWork.CreateRepository(tableType, uoW);
```

CreateRepository returns a dynamic type

```
public static dynamic CreateRepository(string targetType, DbContext context)
{
    Type genericType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(targetType));
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, new object[] { context });
    return instance;
}
```

context was needed as I had to pass the context to Generic repository through constructor.
In my case this approach had some problems though. 
May be this helps you.

Comment: What problems did you have with this approach, if you don't mind me asking? Because I think I'm heading down the same path..

Comment: The problem was I had to use lambda to filter some records but you cannot use lambda with dynamic objects.

Comment: Can't you just cast the dynamic to your type and use lambda?